# How to reconstruct RF signal using IQ data

Tags: digital-communications, modulation, quadrature

I have a complex IQ signal: $s =  X  + Yi$. I know my original $f_0$ was $5\textrm{ MHz}$.

I can calculate the magnitude/amplitude of $s$: $A = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$
and phase, $\phi = \arctan\left(\frac YX\right) $

But how can I reconstruct the signal using this frequency, amplitude and phase data?

I need the output as a time varying signal which incorporates the amplitude and phase information from the IQ data. I have found [this](http://folk.ntnu.no/htorp/Undervisning/TTK10/IQdemodulation.pdf):

> The reconstruction of RF-data from IQ-data is straightforward. It is a
>   reversal of the complex demodulation  in  the  previous  section.  The
>   decimation  is  reversed  by  interpolation.  The  low- pass  filter 
>   cannot  be  reversed,  but  should  be  chosen  without  loss  of 
>   information  in  the  first place.  The  down  mixing  is  reversed 
>   by  up  mixing.  At  last,  the  RF-signal  is  found  by  taking the
>   real-value of the complex up-mixed signal.

But I could really do with a worked example.

**EDIT:**

This MATLAB code appears to do what I want:

```
IQ = resample(IQ,downsampl,1); 

[Z,X] = size(IQ); 
time = [0:Z-1]'*1/F * ones(1,X); 

signal = IQ .* exp(+2*pi*i*time*carrier); 

signal = real(signal);
```

where `resample` resamples IQ at downsampl/1 times.

It is not clear to me what I should use for `downsampl` and what `F` is?

Comment: Here's a [nice visualization](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Circle_cos_sin.gif) which might make it more intuitive.

Comment: What is `i` in your `signal` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RF signal $r(t)$ is obtained from the complex baseband (IQ) signal $s(t)=x(t)+jy(t)$ in the following way:

$$r(t)=\text{Re}\{s(t)e^{j\omega_0t}\}\tag{1}$$

where $\omega_0$ is the carrier frequency (in rad/s). There are two other equivalent representations of $(1)$, where I use $s(t)=x(t)+jy(t)=a(t)e^{j\phi(t)}$:

$$\begin{align}r(t)&=x(t)\cos(\omega_0t)-y(t)\sin(\omega_0t)\tag{2}\\
r(t)&=a(t)\cos(\omega_0t+\phi(t))\tag{3}\end{align}$$

Eq. $(2)$ shows that the I- and Q-components are both modulated by orthogonal carriers, whereas $(3)$ shows that $r(t)$ generally exhibits amplitude modulation as well as phase modulation.

The quote in your question suggests that in the respective text the signals are all represented as discrete-time signals, hence the decimation and interpolation stages.

Comment: Ok. I understand above. I think I can use: 
I=real(s)
Q=imag(s)

fc = 5000000; % Carrier frequency in Hz

C1 = I .* sin(2*pi * fc * t);
C2 = Q .* cos(2*pi * fc * t);
rf = C1 + C2; but what to use for t?

Comment: @2one: If $B$ is the bandwidth of $s(t)$, and if you want to satisfy the Nyquist sampling theorem, you must sample at $f_s>2(f_c+B)$. Then you sample by setting $t=n/f_s$ with integer $n$.

Comment: @2one: If the answer was helpful, please accept it by clicking on the check mark to its left.

Comment: please could you help me with the question edit?

Comment: @2one: I can't say much more than I did in my previous comment. *You* have to know the bandwidth of your IQ data, you have to know the sampling rate of the IQ data, and the frequency of the carrier. You choose the new sampling frequency according to the formula in my previous comment. E.g., if the RF sampling frequency is 20MHz and the IQ sampling frequency is 2 MHz, then the upsampling/interpolation factor is 10. And `F` in your code is the new sampling frequency (20 MHz in my example).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the received I/Q signal $X(t) + jY(t)$ directly, and feed it back directly to your RF IQ mixer/upconverter.

Signal to transmit = $X(t)cos(2\pi f_0t) - Y(t)sin(2\pi f_0t)$

Comment: Would you add some details or source of information, thanks.